# Getting the companion object for my Actor

Tags: scala

When I check the scala doc for Actor react method, I see: See the companion object's react method.
Is this something I can only know runtime? Or how do I find out who the campanion object is?

Note: I know campanion objects are the object with the same name of the corresponding class. So just looking to find out what's going on in this particular case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Paulp did some experiment to achieve that at runtime, please take a look at this thread:
https://groups.google.com/d/topic/scala-language/b9oYVIX8O2c/discussion